# Plist cannot be read ... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, plist

I have got a plist in my Resources folder called "levelconfig.plist" and I want to read something out of it.

I did the following :

```
-(NSString *) dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"levelconfig.plist"];


}

-(void) readPlist{
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSLog(@"%@",array);
        NSLog(@"%@", filePath);

    }


}
```

And in the ccTouchesBegan method I call :

```
[self readPlist];
```

My plist contains an array, that should be displayed right ? Is it a good idea to store level data in a .plist file ?

plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Root</key>
    <array>
        <string>sunday</string>
        <string>monday</string>
        <integer>44</integer>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: so what's actually the question or error you have? and, pls, post you list file content here too.

Comment: there is no error, it just does not read it. If I remove `code` if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){ `code` it returns (null). So it's empty I guess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first read the dictionary as specified in your plist. For example:

```
NSString *mainPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *itemPositionPlistLocation = [mainPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];
NSDictionary * itemPositions = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:itemPositionPlistLocation];
NSArray * items = [itemPositions objectForKey:@"Root"];
NSLog(@"%@", items);
```

I'm not sure what you are doing with your other code but two lines suffice to load the file. Please excuse the variable names; I quickly adapted this from my current project. Also, make sure you release the Array and Dictionary in dealloc or wherever appropriate.

Comment: I have got another problem: If I want to read out a dictionary within the dictionary, how would i do that ?

Comment: is that correct ? It is actually two dictionaries within another ... `NSArray * items = [[[[itemPositions objectForKey:@"level1"]objectForKey:@"hexposition"]objectForKey:@"hexagon1"]objectForKey:@"xVal"];`

Comment: If it's two dictionaries, then you first read the first dictionary (`NSDictionary * itemPositions = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:itemPositionPlistLocation];
` in my example) then the second, `NSDictionary *dict2 = [itemPositions objectForKey@"Root"`. This assumes 'Root' is your dictionary. (As in, in your plist above, `array` is replaced with `dictionary`. I believe your code would work, but I get dizzy looking at all those nested statements ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's in your resources folder? In that case you aren't building the path properly. You will probably want to use `[NSBundle pathForResource:]` ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource%3aofType%3a))

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Yes it is in the folder ... I wouldn't know how to use NSBundle as I am new to programming. Could you possibly give me some advice on it ?

Comment: The docs I linked to have a very good example of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your pList file is a Dictionary that has an array in the Root key and you are reading it in to an Array.

```
-(void) readPlist{
        NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Root"]];
        NSLog(@"%@",array);
        NSLog(@"%@", filePath);
        [dict release];
        [array release];

    }
}
```