# Can not read plist file?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, plist, xcode5.1

I have a annoying error which came suddenly. I wanted to read a .plist file. However it is currently impossible. It worked yesterday, even 3 hours ago and then my app crashed on the simulator and on the device. I have listened to this tutorial (twice) (and others):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Oy-evy2xD8

Googled many stackoverflow solutions (beside these two...):

[Plist cannot be read ... What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371465/plist-cannot-be-read-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

[Can't read from plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275502/cant-read-from-plist)

And still I did not get one step closer to a soultion.

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];

documentDirectory = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testPlist.plist"];


NSLog(@" documentDirectory: - %@ ",documentDirectory);

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentDirectory])
{
    NSLog(@" The file exits! ! !");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@" The file DOES NOT exits !!!");
}

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: documentDirectory]) {
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testPlist" ofType:@"plist"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:documentDirectory error:&error];

    NSLog(@"plist is copied to Directory");
}


NSDictionary * plistDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:documentDirectory];
NSMutableDictionary * plistMutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:documentDirectory];
NSArray *items = [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"Root"];

//NSMutableArray *itemsFromMutableDict = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//[itemsFromMutableDict addObject:[plistDictionary objectForKey:@"Root"]];

NSLog(@" Path : %@ ",documentDirectory);
NSLog(@" Items in array = %@", items);
NSLog(@" array count = %i", [items count]);
NSLog(@" Why is this %@ ?",[plistDictionary objectForKey:@"Root"]);
```

**The output is :**

```
2014-06-12 11:24:25.894 PlistTestingProject[1879:60b]  All paths : /Users/webbite_mladen/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/A1A7D9E3-BFDE-4C52-8C5F-28F0D88D6F5F/Documents 

2014-06-12 11:24:25.896 PlistTestingProject[1879:60b]  documentDirectory: - /Users/webbite_mladen/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/A1A7D9E3-BFDE-4C52-8C5F-28F0D88D6F5F/Documents/testPlist.plist 

2014-06-12 11:24:25.897 PlistTestingProject[1879:60b]  The file exits! ! !

2014-06-12 11:24:25.897 PlistTestingProject[1879:60b]  Path : /Users/webbite_mladen/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/A1A7D9E3-BFDE-4C52-8C5F-28F0D88D6F5F/Documents/testPlist.plist 

2014-06-12 11:24:25.898 PlistTestingProject[1879:60b]  Items in array = (null)

2014-06-12 11:24:25.898 PlistTestingProject[1879:60b]  array count = 0

2014-06-12 11:24:25.899 PlistTestingProject[1879:60b]  Why is this (null) ?
```

It seems that I cannot access the plist file.

The plist file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Root</key>
        <array>
            <string>sunday</string>
            <string>monday</string>
            <integer>44</integer>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple solution finally worked:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlistFile"
                                                              ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this..

NSDictionary *dictRoot = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file_name" ofType:@"plist"]];

NSArray *arrRoot = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dictRoot objectForKey:@"Root"]];